# Unable to share directory on dc++

Tags: 12.10

I am using linuxDC++ on Ubuntu 12.10.

I am unable to share folders under file->preferences->sharing->add. Everytime I do that I get an error message saying:

```
The temporary download directory cannot be shared
```

Please could someone help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried creating and sharing a new directory, cause it seems to me u r trying to share the same directory where your temporary files go while youŕ downloading from dc++. Go to preferences and choose diferent directorys for the finished downloads and the temporary ongoing downloads, after that you can share the completed downloads directory. If it doesnt work, create and share a brand new directory and give us feedback.

Comment: I tried this, but its not working!